# Blazor Server: import library then immediately call a method from it

Tags: razor, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to import a Javascript file into a component OnAfterRenderAsync and then immediately call a function from it. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. I always get a "could not find 'function name'" exception. I've tried adding a reference to the function to the window object but that just morphs the exception into "'function name' is not defined ReferenceError".

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "./scripts/TestJS.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("functionName", "strMsg");
    }
}
```

and this is the simple JS function I'm trying to call

```
function functionName(strMsg){
    console.log(strMsg);
}
```

Ive also tried wrapping the import calls into a Task.Run with the thinking I was calling a JS method before the file had finished loading. Breakpoints and watching the DOM load prove that the JS is loaded onto the page with a 304 status BEFORE I try to call a method from the file.

```
Task.Run(() => JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("import", "./scripts/TestJS.js")).Wait();
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("functionName", "strMsg");
```

If I add the JS and then call a function from a separate event all works fine it seems, but I have to figure out how to import a JS file and then IMMEDIATELY be able to call it. If someone can help I would be very appreciative. If more code is needed I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first call should return an `IJSObjectReference`, then use the reference to invoke the JS module function.

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/TestJS.js");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("functionName", "strMsg");
    }
}
```

You need to also add `export` keyword to your function:

```js
export function functionName(strMsg){
    console.log(strMsg);
}
```

[JavaScript isolation in JavaScript modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules)

Comment: How would this work in the context of a third party library? I have the same issue trying to use Leaflet and importing Leaflet js, markercluster js, and esri vector tile js files. I'm assuming I'd have to import those files into my main JS file that is calling them through a JS import * as L from '' type of statement?

Comment: Yes, that should work.